# batch delete smaller of two files

Tags: python, perl

I am looking for a way to do a batch rename of a bunch of files based on the criteria mentioned below:

The filelist looks similar to this, and should be alpha-numeric:

- A20100102-1.loc.txt
- A20100102.loc.txt
- A20100103-1.loc.txt
- A20100103.loc.txt
  ...etc.

The following pseudo-code is pretty close to the way I want it to behave, but I'm trying to figure out if sed, awk, python, perl, or a bash script is the way to go (I'm examining the options in order to figure out which implementation I might want to delve deeper into):

```
for all_files_in_dir:{
  if(currentfile.name is_close_to previousfile.name){  //maybe regex here
    var small_file = find_smaller_file_filename(currentfile.filesize, previousfile.filesize);
    sys.remove(small_file);
  }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Why dont you first decide, what you want to write solution using ?

Comment: OK, python might be the best for me.

Comment: What do you mean by the "smaller" or "larger" file?  Are you looking at the file size?  Which filename comes first alphabetically?  Something else?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield yes; alphabetically. smaller/larger: filesize.  thanks for clarifying

Comment: @jml then edit your post. And also retag it  !!

Comment: Do you want to "batch rename" or delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My entry: not so concise, but hopefully readable.

```
import sys, os
from collections import defaultdict

filenames = sys.argv[1:]

# collect like-named files
groups = defaultdict(set)
for filename in filenames:
    key = filename.split('.')[0].split("-")[0]
    groups[key].add(filename)

# work on each group
for names in groups.values():
    target_name = sorted(names)[0] # or min(names, key=len), or whatever
    largest_file = max(names, key=os.path.getsize)

    os.rename(largest_file, target_name)

    to_remove = names.difference((largest_file, target_name))
    for name in to_remove:
        os.remove(name)
```

Comment: i found your code extremely readable; thank you.  i haven't tried it yet, but i wanted to ask if this will rename files appropriately if they have "mistaken" characters that were tacked on based on duplicates by the OS - for ex., if 'A20100102-1.loc.txt' is the larger file, it looks like it handles renaming it to 'A20100102.loc.txt, correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
import re

def rm_smaller_of(regex, dir):
    for entry in os.listdir(dir):
        if re.match(regex, entry[:9]):
            matches = [(os.stat(f).st_size, f) for f in os.listdir(dir) 
                        if f[:9] == entry[:9]]
            matches.sort(reverse=True)
            for d in matches[1:]:
                os.remove(d[1])
```

I think this should work.

```
>>> rm_smaller_of('[A-Z]\d{8}$', '/home/you/list')
```

Comment: i get an error on "for entry in files:" because 'files' isn't defined.  what am i missing?

Comment: At first I was going to assign `os.listdir(dir)` to `files`, but I thought, as the files get deleted, it could get ugly. I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post a solution in Perl, just because you did not consider it as a possibility :)

```
$currentPrefix = "";
$previousFile = "";
while (<*.txt>) {
  /([A-Z]+[0-9]+)-?[0-9]*.loc.txt/;
  if ($1 eq $currentPrefix) {
    if (-s $_ < -s $previousFile) {
      unlink($_);
    } else {
      unlink($previousFile);
      $previousFile = $_;
    }
  } else {
    $currentPrefix = $1;
    $previousFile = $_;
  }
}
```

And another solution in python:

```
import glob
import os
import re

currentPrefix = ""
previousFile = ""
for filename in sorted(glob.glob('*.txt')):
  match = re.match(r'([A-Z]+[0-9]+)-?[0-9]*.loc.txt', filename)
  if match and match.group(1) == currentPrefix:
    if os.stat(filename).st_size < os.stat(previousFile).st_size:
      os.remove(filename)
    else:
      os.remove(previousFile)
      previousFile = filename
  else:
    currentPrefix = match.group(1)
    previousFile = filename
```

Note that you need to sort the files, because glob does not return them by lexicographic order…

Comment: this worked for me; i modified it slightly to handle renaming of files if necessary.